# LINQ - Group By and Sum

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a `DataTable` (`CategoryUnsummarised`) which has three columns: `Category`, `DataSort` and `Net`.

This is used to drive a report showing totals by category. The reporting application is Devexpress XtraReports. This is within their layout scripting.

This table has several rows of different Net for each Category. The DataSort column is only there to ensure that the category "Other" appears last in the list when sorted. It will only ever be 1 or 2.

An example of the data:

[image]

I am trying to create a new table which is a sum of Net grouped by Category and Datasort.

Desired data:

[image]

The below is what I have tried, based on other examples on StockOverflow, however it is giving me an error.

```
    ' Sets columns in CategorySummary table
        CategorySummary = CategoryUnsummarised.clone()


    ' Now summarises the rows. Groups by Category and Datasort, and gives sum total.

        Dim CatGroups = CategoryUnsummarised.AsEnumerable().
            GroupBy(Function(row) New With {
                Key .Category = row.Field(Of String)("Category"),
                Key .DataSort = row.Field(Of integer)("DataSort")
            })

        For Each GroupRow In CatGroups
            CategorySummary.Rows.Add(GroupRow.Key.Category, GroupRow.Sum(Function(row) row.Field(Of decimal)("Net")), GroupRow.Key.DataSort)
        Next
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

[image]

If I declare GroupRow as a variable, it allows the code, however then I get the following:

[image]

As far as I can see, the Linq code is valid.

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On`...

Comment: I've run your sample, and it works with or without option explicit/option strict. It's correct.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it's valid code. I can only assume that the XtraReports application does not like Linq queries within its scripting editor.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `GroupBy` method:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("Category")
    dt.Columns.Add("Net")
    dt.Rows.Add("Hat", 1)
    dt.Rows.Add("Hat", 2)
    dt.Rows.Add("Gloves", 3)
    dt.Rows.Add("Gloves", 4)

    Dim dtSum = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(
        Function(row)
            Return row.Field(Of String)("Category").ToString()
        End Function).ToDictionary(Function(grp)
                                       Return New KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)(grp.Key, grp.Sum(Function(row)
                                                                                                        Return Integer.Parse(row("Net").ToString())
                                                                                                    End Function))
                                   End Function)

End Sub
```

This should give an idea how to achieve what you want.

Comment: You need `Dim dt As New DataTable()
dt.Columns.Add("Category")
dt.Columns.Add("DataSort", GetType(Integer))
dt.Columns.Add("Net", GetType(Decimal))` for this to match the question

Comment: @reckface It's totally irrelevant to the answer. It shows what method to use and how to achieve desired result

Comment: fair enough. The op wants an output table that matches the input table but with the sum of the net column. His error shouldn't even occur, this may not address that.